# How to get raw data from pcap file and decode it in java

Tags: java, wireshark

I'm studying about Networking .I had sent a file image between two pc by ICMP then capture by wireshark. I'm try to get raw data from pcap file and decode it to get data that I just had sent by java. I had taken a lot of times but I dont know how i can do it. I really wanna you do me a favor. Sorry because of English not my mother tongue.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630646/parsing-pcap-taken-from-wireshark-file-using-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing pcap taken from wireshark file using - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630646/parsing-pcap-taken-from-wireshark-file-using-java)